# Is It Possible to Combine Array Values from Separate Functions Together?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

When my code is run you can see that when a user enters in a quantity for a room, selects a check in and check out date and hits submit, a table appears with the room name, the quantity entered for the selected room and the price based on the number of rooms. In Addition, another table appears with the number of days from check in to check out and the total. The Total is suppose to be the number of days multiplied by the price.

The first table that appears is created with the outputArray() function shown in the below javascript. The second table is created with the CalcTotals() function. I need to find a way to multiply the number of days selected with the price and output it as the total. Is there any way to combine these two things being that they are calculated in separate functions?

```js
function QtyVal()
  {
     var x,y,z,text;

          // Get the value of the input of the room quantities
      x = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
      y = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
   z = document.getElementById("qty3").value;


         if (y < 1 || y > 8)
       {
        text = "please enter quantity from 1 to 8";
       }

    else if (x < 1 || x > 8)
     {
     text = "please enter quantity from 1 to 8";

     }

        else if (z > 1 || isNaN(z))
       {

       text = "Due to limited availability, " +
              "guests are only allowed to " +
              "book one Penthouse Suite per stay";
                   }


             else if (x == '' && y == '' && z == '')
                {
                  text = "Please select a room";
              }

             else
                   {
           text = "";

        var n1 = new Array(); // allocate empty array
                       var n2 = new Array(); // allocate another empty array


                      n1.push(document.getElementById("qty1").value);
       n1.push(document.getElementById("qty2").value);
       n1.push(document.getElementById("qty3").value);


                      outputArray(n1, document.getElementById( "results" ) );
                      CalcTotals(n2, document.getElementById( "totals" ) );
       }
       document.getElementById("book").innerHTML = text;
  }



function outputArray(theArray, output )
{
   var content = "<table>" + "<thead><th>Room Type</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>";


   // output the type, quantity and price of each array element
   var length = theArray.length; // get array's length once before loop
   var type = ["Deluxe Room", "Spa Room", "Penthouse Suite"];


      for ( var i = 0; i < type.length; ++i )

          if(theArray[i] == theArray[0])
    {
       content += "<tr><td>" + type[i] + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td><td>" + "$"+ (theArray[0] * 150.00) + "</td></tr>";
          }
      else if(theArray[i] == theArray[1])
    {
     content += "<tr><td>" + type[i] + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td><td>" + "$"+ (theArray[1] * 220.00) + "</td></tr>";
    }
   else if(theArray[i] == theArray[2])
    {
     content += "<tr><td>" + type[i] + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td><td>" + "$"+ (theArray[2] * 450.00) + "</td></tr>";
    }
   else
    {
     content += "<tr><td>" + type[i] + "</td><td>" + theArray[i] + "</td><td>" + "$"+ (theArray[i] * 0.00) + "</td></tr>";
    }

   content += "</tbody></table>";
   output.innerHTML = content; // place the table in the output element
}

window.addEventListener( "onclick", QtyVal, false );





function CkInVal()
  {
   var In = document.getElementById("ckIn").value;
   var Out = document.getElementById("ckOut").value;
   var today  = new Date();

      if ( In < today )
   {
     text = "Please select today's date or later";
      }

      else
      {
        text = "Select a check out date";
      }
    document.getElementById("ckDay").innerHTML = text;
 }




function CkOutVal()
  {
   var In = document.getElementById("ckIn").value;
   var Out = document.getElementById("ckOut").value;

   if (Out <= In)
      {
    text = "Check out must be a day or later past the check in date";
      }

   else
      {
      text = "Your Stay is from " + In + " to " + Out;
      }
      document.getElementById("ckDay").innerHTML = text;
 }




function CalcTotals(theArray, output)
{
   var content = "<table>" + "<thead><th>Days</th><th>Total</th></thead><tbody>";

   var length = theArray.length;
   var x = [ , ];


   var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds in a day
   var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById("ckIn").value);
   var secondDate = new Date(document.getElementById("ckOut").value);

   var Daydiff = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));


    for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i )

        {
          content += "<tr><td>" + Daydiff + "</td><td>" +  + "</td></tr>";
        } // end for

   content += "</tbody></table>";
   output.innerHTML = content;
}
window.addEventListener( "onclick", QtyVal, false );
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  <title>Rooms and Rates</title>

 </head>

 <body>

     <header>

   <div align = "center">
      <h1> Monte Carlo Hotel </h1>
   </div>

   <img src = "Images/Monte Carlo 1.jpg"
     alt = "Monte Carlo Hotel"
           align = "left"/>

   <br><h4>Monte Carlo
   <br>3770 Las Vegas Blvd.
   <br>Las Vegas, NV 89109
   <br>(702) 730-7777</h4>

   <a href = "Index.html">
   <div class = "icon">
     Home
   </div></a>

   <a href="Amenities.html">
   <div class = "icon">
     Amenities/Facilities
   </div></a>

   <a href = "Entertainment.html">
      <div class = "icon">
     Entertainment
   </div></a>

   <a href = "Membership.html">
   <div class = "icon">
     Membership
            </div></a>

     </header>


      <table>
      <tr>
      <th>Room Type</th>
      <th>View</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   <th>Rate</th>
   <th>No. of Rooms</th>
      </tr>

    <tr><form id = "bookform">

       <td align = "center" class = "RmType" value = "Deluxe Room">Deluxe Rooms</td>

       <td><img src = "http://img.lasvegasdirect.com/aria-city-center-las-vegas-deluxe-room-02.jpg"
        alt = "deluxe room"
        align = "center"/>
     </td>

       <td>You'll find everything you need for an enjoyable stay, including your choice of one king or two queen beds with pillow top mattresses,
           crisp sheets, fresh and fluffy white bedding, contemporary accents, and all the amenities to make your stay comfortable and convenient.
         <ul>
         <li>40 Inch HD TV</li>
       <li>Cable TV</li>
         <li>Italian Marble Enrty & Bathrooms</li>
         <li>Bath and Body Products</li>
       <li>Mini Fridge</li>
       <li>Iron & Ironing Board</li>
         </ul>
      </td>

      <td>$150/night</td>

      <td colspan = "3">
        <input type = "number" id = "qty1" min = "1" max = "8">
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align = "center">Spa Rooms</td>

        <td><img src = "http://www.montecarlo.com/images/rooms/Spa-suite.jpg"
        alt = "spa room"
        align = "center"/>
      </td>

        <td>Need a little break from all the excitement? You won't have to go far when you're staying in one of our Spa Rooms.
         Release yourself to your personal oasis in a hydrotherapy whirlpool tub. Relaxtion is just a door turn away.
        <ul>
           <li>Italian Marble Bath</li>
        <li>Seperate Rainforest Style Shower</li>
        <li>Seperate Sitting Area</li>
        <li>Wet bar and Fridge</li>
        <li>40 Inch HD w/ Cable</li>
        <li>Bath and Body Products</li>
        <li>Iron & Ironing Board</li>
        </ul>
     </td>

     <td>$220/night</td>

     <td colspan = "3">
        <input type = "number" id = "qty2" min = "1" max = "8">

     </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
       <td align = "center" class = "RmType" value = "Penthouse">Penthouse Suite</td>

       <td><img src = "http://condohotelcenter.com/images/martin-Home%20Four%208795%20(2).jpg"
        alt = "penthouse"
        align = "center"/>
     </td>

       <td>Live life to the fullest at the top. Indulge in this home away from with endless pampering,
       perks and suite assistants that will wait on you hand and foot. Discover exclusive living.
      <ul>
    <li>2000 sq. ft.</li>
    <li>Entertainment room w/ pool table</li>
    <li>HD TVs throughout the suite</li>
    <li>Wet bar and prestocked fridge per your requests</li>
    <li>Master and 2nd bedroom with Ultra King</li>
    <li>Huge Kohler Chromatherapy steam shower</li>
    <li>15" in-mirror integrated TV in master bath</li>
    <li>Hydrotherapy soaking tub</li>
    <li>Additional 1/2 bath</li>
    <p><b>Note: Due to limited availability, guests are only allowed to book one Penthouse Suite per stay.</b></p>
      </ul>
   </td>

   <td>$450/night</td>

   <td colspan = "3" >
    <input type = "number" name = "Penthouse" id = "qty3"  min = "1" max = "1">
      </td>
    </tr>
     </table>


      <div align = "middle">

      <br><br>Check In Date:
     <input type = "date" onChange = "CkInVal()" id = "ckIn" >

        Check Out Date:
     <input type = "date" onChange = "CkOutVal()" id = "ckOut" >


       <p></p>
      <button type = "button" onClick ="QtyVal(); CalcPrice()">SUBMIT</button>
    <br><br>
      <button type = "reset" id = "rst">Reset</button>

    <p  id = "ckDay"></p> <p id = "book"></p>

   </div>


   <br>


     <div align = "middle" id = "results"></div>

     <div align = "middle" id = "totals"></div>

           </form>






     <footer align = "center">
     <br><a href = "Index.html">Homepage</a>  | <a href = "Amenities.html">Amenities</a> | <a href = "Entertainment.html">Entertainment</a> | <a href = "Membership.html">Membership/Comments</a>
     <br><br>3770 Las Vegas Blvd. Las Vegas, NV 89109
     <br>Email Us: <a href = "mailto:montecarlolasvegas@aol.com">montecarlolasvegas@aol.com</a>.
   <br>Phone: (702) 730-7777
   <br>Fax: (702) 703-7878
   <br>Copyright &copy; 2015 MGM Resorts International. All rights reserved.
        </footer>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `CalcTotals` needs both - the number of rooms and the time. Also I would separate the calculation from the generation of the output. First do all calculations and put the results into an object. Then pass that into the functions that produce the html.

Answer (score 0):

You compute the price, type and quantity of the rooms in `outputArray`. Just call `CalcTotals` at the end of `outputArray` instead of `QtyVal` You can give `outputArray` the information it needs as an argument. If you want to book every rooms for the same amount of time you can just pass `type * price * number` added for all three types of rooms if necessary and let `CalcTotals` compute the number of days and multiply it with the sum given as the argument from `outputArray`.

I hope that was not too badly explained?